# Execute function periodically or when an event fires

Tags: python, flask

I am working on Python's Flask server side code where there is a background task which runs periodically and executes a function (note that 'periodically' is not so hardline, execute once and then after x seconds also works). But I also need it to execute the same function immediately when the server receives a request (and then resume the background task).

This kind of reminds me of the *SELECT* system call in C, where the system waits for a timeout or until a packet arrives.

Here is what I came up minimally after looking up a lot of answers.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import threading, os, time

POOL_TIME = 2

myThread = threading.Thread()

def pollAndExecute(a='|'):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.time(), a)
    # time.sleep(1)
    myThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, pollAndExecute)
    myThread.start() 

def startWork():
    global myThread
    myThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, pollAndExecute)
    myThread.start()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ping', methods=['POST'])
def ping():
    global myThread
    myThread.cancel()
    pollAndExecute("@")
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    startWork()
    app.run(port=5001)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

But the output clearly says that it is not behaving properly after there is a request (sent using `curl -X POST http://localhost:5001/ping`)

Please guide me as to how to correct this or are there any other ways to do it. Just FYI, in the original code, there are various database updates in the *pollAndExecute()* as well and I need to take care that there are no race conditions between polling and ping. Needless to say, only one copy of the function should execute at a particular time (preferably in a single thread).

Comment: Can you explain how the output is wrong? It seems fine to me.

Comment: @gkhnavarro The *pollAndExecute()* will take atleast 1 second to run. So the time gaps should be atleast a second between the consecutive execution of the function. But see the consecutive times after the request. They are about 0.5 seconds apart.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I made for your problem. I used a priority queue that takes in data to be run with the `printTime` function. The background and flask functions are two different threads that push data into the priority queue, which should prioritize the flask call over the background one. Notice how it now waits for the current thread to finish before executing another one.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import threading, os, time

from threading import Thread, Lock
from queue import PriorityQueue

POOL_TIME = 2

lock = Lock()

def printTime(a='|'):
    time.sleep(1) # Simulate process taking 1 sec
    print(time.time(), a)

jobs = PriorityQueue()

class Queue(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            _, data = jobs.get()
            printTime(data)


class backGroundProcess(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2) # Background process enqueues a job every 2 secs
            jobs.put((0,"|"))

class flaskProcess(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        jobs.put((1,"@"))


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ping', methods=['POST'])
def ping():
    flaskThread = flaskProcess()
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    backGroundProcess()
    Queue()
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(port=5001)
```

The above snippet may be a little verbose because I used classes, but this should get you started.